# Egit's Team context menu has only one option: Apply patch

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm sure that I inadvertently checked off a box somewhere which caused this problem where all of the other options are missing: fetch, push, merge, etc.  On my other machines, when I right click on a project and select "Team", I'll get all of the menu options.  On one laptop, all I get is a single option, "Apply patch..."  I can go into the Git Repository View and get at all of the other GIT functions there, which is what I have to do when I want to synch up to a remote.

I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this so I can access all of the git functions from the regular editor view and it's driving me crazy. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the `.project` and `.classpath` are not where the sources are? Are they located differently when compared to other projects on your other machines?

Comment: The .project and .classpath files look like they're in the correct place.

Comment: Ok, just checking. I suppose you still have this issue? Did you try to make another clone and to re-import that project (in a separate Eclipse workspace), to see if the issue is repeatable?

Comment: Still have the issue.  Haven't had time to re-import since that's a pain in the ass to do right now.

Comment: So the best test would be to try and import your project on a fresh Eclipse installation (which you can setup *separately* from your current Eclipse): the idea is to not touch anything that you have right now, and see if the issue persists in a new installation.

Comment: Did my late answer solve your problem? If yes i would by happy if you accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, your project isn't associated with the Git Team Provider. I ran into the same problem when setting up eclipse juno with EGit.

- If not done already, initialise or clone your existing project with git
- Rightclick on your project and select:
- Team -> Share Project ... -> Git -> [check your project] -> Finish

Now all the Git options you were looking for should be in place.

HTH, Martin

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the suggestion. This solved my problem. But I am left wondering what the problem was and from an eclipse point of view what did these steps do that solved the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll try it out.  Eclipse has some strange ways of doing things.

Comment: Thanks man! This definitely solved the problem. The asker should mark this answer as valid ;)

Comment: Glad it worked out, @aceperry. Do you like to accept my answer as solution?